# Find the proportion of rows verifying a condition in a single SQL query

Tags: sql, count

Suppose I have a `sales` table which is as follows:

```
ID    |      Price  
----------------------
1              0.33                
2              1.5               
3              0.5                
4              10                
5              0.99
```

I would like to find, in a single query, the proportion of rows verifying a given condition. For example, if the condition is `Price < 1`, the result should be 3/5 = 0.6.

The only workaround that I have found so far is :

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN Price < 1
            THEN 1 
            WHEN Price >= 1
            THEN 0
            END
          )/COUNT(*)
FROM sales
```

but is there a way to do this without `CASE` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `IF`:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(Price < 1, 1, 0))/COUNT(*) FROM sales
```

-but it's no big difference from `CASE` (your logic here is correct)

You may want to use `WHERE` (to sum only Price<1) - but since you're using total COUNT it's not valid in your case. Another option: get total count separately:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(sales.Price)/total_count
FROM
  sales
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNt(*) AS total_count FROM sales) AS c
WHERE
-- you're summing 1 or 0 depending of Price, so your sum is 
-- just count where Price<1
  sales.Price<1
```